# TAILS: Administration password not recognized

Tags: tails

I created a USB stick (16 GB) with Tails to run on my PC (Windows 10).

My problem is that the administration password entered in the welcome screen is well understood by Tails, and the access to Persistent is granted.

For all other actions that ask for the administration password, like opening a root terminal or access to the PC hard disks, the password is not recognized.

I have read a lot of times Tails documentation and web entries about Tails, but I have not found the information that I have missed. I’ll be grateful if you have any idea about the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The main password you enter on the Welcome screen is dedicated to the [encrypted Persistent storage](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/persistence/use).

**Not to be confused** with the [Administration password](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/welcome_screen/administration_password/), which allows to run Root terminal, do administrative tasks and access the internal disk for example.

They are 2 separated passwords with different purposes, this adds an extra security layer for TAILS.

Just ask if you need more details.